# Undefined reference to `clock_gettime` although `-lrt` is given

Tags: linux, linker, libc

I've give `-lrt` as the last linker flag to the compiler. But still getting this error.

```
arif@khost:~/sak/sak.exosip$ gcc eXo_init.c -I/opt/osip2/include -I/opt/exosip/include  -L/opt/osip2/lib -L/opt/exosip/lib -leXosip2 -losipparser2 -losip2 -lrt
/opt/osip2/lib/libosip2.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The man page says :

```
NAME
       clock_getres, clock_gettime, clock_settime - clock and time functions

SYNOPSIS
       #include <time.h>

       int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *res);

       int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);

       int clock_settime(clockid_t clk_id, const struct timespec *tp);

       Link with -lrt.
```

So i'm kind of confused where i'm doing it wrong.

I've tried to read symbols in `librt.so` with no luck :

```
arif@khost:~/sak/ortp/src/tests$ nm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so 
nm: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so: no symbols
```

**UPDATE 1** The reason i can't read symbols out of `librt.so` is that they are "stripped". Where can i get the symbol names ?

```
arif@khost:~/sak/ortp/src/tests$ file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[sha1]=0x375b2c35c4e6503a5d1a88ab6f76f5b6e0ee81df, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, stripped
```

**UPDATE 2**

Well things become very confusing because the following test code compiles and runs just fine :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **arge) {
    struct timespec tps, tpe;
    if ((clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tps) != 0)
        || (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tpe) != 0)) {
        perror("clock_gettime");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("%lu s, %lu ns\n", tpe.tv_sec-tps.tv_sec,tpe.tv_nsec-tps.tv_nsec);
    return 0;
}
```

Built with

```
arif@khost:~/sak/sak.exosip$ gcc what.c -lrt
```

**UPDATE3** The code i'm trying compile :

```
#include <eXosip2/eXosip.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int ex_init(int port)
{
    struct eXosip_t *eXcontext;
    int i;
    TRACE_INITIALIZE(6, stdout);
    i = eXosip_init(eXcontext);
    if (i != 0)
        return -1;

    i = eXosip_listen_addr(eXcontext, IPPROTO_UDP, NULL, port, AF_INET, 0);
    if (i != 0) {
        eXosip_quit(eXcontext);
        fprintf (stderr, "could not initialize transport layer\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(ex_init(1000))
        printf("success \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you give us the original offending code ? Thanks

Comment: I don't have to work with gcc cmd lines much, but would it help to move the reference to `-lrt` closer to the front of the cmd line? Good luck.

Comment: @MatthR3D given as you have asked. As you can see, its a very trivial code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well the problem is solved If i pass this linker flag

```
-Wl,--no-as-needed
```

Before the library list in command line.

Why this works because in my platform, linker is always passed with `-Wl,--as-needed`.

From `ld` manual :

```
--as-needed
       --no-as-needed
           This option affects ELF DT_NEEDED tags for dynamic libraries
           mentioned on the command line after the --as-needed option.
           Normally the linker will add a DT_NEEDED tag for each dynamic
           library mentioned on the command line, regardless of whether the
           library is actually needed or not.  --as-needed causes a DT_NEEDED
           tag to only be emitted for a library that satisfies an undefined
           symbol reference from a regular object file or, if the library is
           not found in the DT_NEEDED lists of other libraries linked up to
           that point, an undefined symbol reference from another dynamic
           library.  --no-as-needed restores the default behaviour.
```

So when `--as-needed` is given before a library , liker only links with the libraries which are given in `NEEDED` section of the library.

For example,

```
-Wl,--as-needed -llibA -llibB -llibC
```

Here --as-needed is given before `libA`. So during linking, linker will examine the `NEEDED` section of `libA`. If in `NEEDED` section of `libA` lists only `libC`, then the `libB` will not be linked.

This specific problem occurred because

```
arif@khost:~/sak/sak.exosip$ objdump -p /opt/osip2/lib/libosip2.so.10 | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libosipparser2.so.10
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

`libosip2` does not lists `librt` as `NEEDED`.

If i pass `--no-as-needed`, then all the libraries will be linked regardless of what is given in ELF's `NEEDED` section.

Although this should not be the case because,

```
arif@khost:~/sak/sak.exosip$ nm --demangle /opt/osip2/lib/libosip2.so.10 | grep clock_gettime
                 U clock_gettime
```

It has undefined symbol `clock_gettime` which is provided by `librt.so`.

Well its actually a fault of the `libosip2` devs that their `autotools` is not working with `--as-needed`.

The link command used by osip:

```
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/ict_fsm.o .libs/ist_fsm.o .libs/nict_fsm.o .libs/nist_fsm.o .libs/ict.o .libs/ist.o .libs/nict.o .libs/nist.o .libs/fsm_misc.o .libs/osip.o .libs/osip_transaction.o .libs/osip_event.o .libs/port_fifo.o .libs/osip_dialog.o .libs/osip_time.o .libs/port_sema.o .libs/port_thread.o .libs/port_condv.o   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/arif/sak/osip/src/osipparser2/.libs -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/osip2-test/lib -lnsl ../osipparser2/.libs/libosipparser2.so    -Wl,-soname -Wl,libosip2.so.10 -o .libs/libosip2.so.10.0.0
```

So its not linking with `librt` and thats why its not listing `librt` in its `NEEDED` list

If configured with :

```
 LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -lrt" ./configure --prefix=/opt/osip2-test/
```

Then the link command becomes :

```
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/ict_fsm.o .libs/ist_fsm.o .libs/nict_fsm.o .libs/nist_fsm.o .libs/ict.o .libs/ist.o .libs/nict.o .libs/nist.o .libs/fsm_misc.o .libs/osip.o .libs/osip_transaction.o .libs/osip_event.o .libs/port_fifo.o .libs/osip_dialog.o .libs/osip_time.o .libs/port_sema.o .libs/port_thread.o .libs/port_condv.o   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/arif/sak/osip/src/osipparser2/.libs -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/osip2-test/lib -lnsl ../osipparser2/.libs/libosipparser2.so -lrt    -Wl,-soname -Wl,libosip2.so.10 -o .libs/libosip2.so.10.0.0
```

So its linking with `librt`. Its also reflected in its ELF:

```
arif@khost:~/sak/osip/src/osip2/.libs$ objdump -p libosip2.so.10 | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libosipparser2.so.10
  NEEDED               librt.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

This patch fixes this :

```
diff --git a/src/osip2/Makefile.am b/src/osip2/Makefile.am
index bb0d8f3..b72c22a 100644
--- a/src/osip2/Makefile.am
+++ b/src/osip2/Makefile.am
@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@ libosip2_la_SOURCES+=port_sema.c port_thread.c port_condv.c
 endif

 libosip2_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info $(LIBOSIP_SO_VERSION) \
- $(FSM_LIB) $(EXTRA_LIB) ../osipparser2/libosipparser2.la -no-undefined
+ $(FSM_LIB) $(EXTRA_LIB) ../osipparser2/libosipparser2.la -no-undefined -lrt


 INCLUDES = -I$(top_srcdir)/includ
```

Relevant usenet discussion thread :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.programmer/VKbARy6W4AY

UPDATE:

osip developer responded to my mail. He fixed it with a different patch (More general solution then mine) 
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/osip.git/commit/?id=bd5b1ad58381e4bfce08bad9b66ad00cd28f9b65

Comment: This is an interesting question, can you also provide the system information (system type) for future readers of this question?